# MySQL: First select 10 newest rows in descending PK order, then the rest of records alphabetically

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table USERS:

```
 id | name
----+------
```

Can you help me with the query that would fetch all rows from the table and:

a) Place 10 rows with highest PK values on top, in **`id DESC`** order;

b) Place all remaining rows ordered by **`name ASC`** order.

Thank you!

Comment: Post your attempts and where you're having trouble with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a tricky question.  The approach I would take is a `join` approach.  Identify the primary keys for the first group using a join (this is happily fast because you are working with primary keys).  Then use the match to that table for the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from table t left outer join
     (select id
      from table t
      order by id desc
      limit 10
     ) t10
     on t.id = t10.id
order by t10.id desc,
         t.name asc;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second sort be by `t.name asc`? I have a doubt though about where the *null* entries will be placed for the `t10.id desc` sort though (I can never remember if *null* comes before or after in sorts).

Comment: Yep. I've noticed that too. Thanks, Gordon. Works great - it was tricky, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First question would be: do you really need this in one single query? I'm really not seeing the use case for such a query to be honest.
It'd be easier to just fetch the 10 biggest ids (storing somewhere the 10th biggest), and then fetch the rest in ascending name order (with a restriction on ids being smaller than the 10th biggest).

Otherwise in a single query, something like this would work, but it doesn't seem very efficient to me (maybe someone will have a better idea).

```
(
    SELECT 
        id, name 
    from 
        USERS 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
)
 UNION
(
    SELECT 
        id, name 
    from 
        USERS 
    WHERE 
        id NOT IN (
            SELECT id, name from USERS ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
        )
    ORDER BY name ASC 
)
```

(or maybe with a `NOT EXISTS` - the inner query will be different - instead of the `NOT IN`)

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh, my bad then. I must confess I can't recall when I used an `union` for the last time (though I always thought it'd always put the first `select` then the `second` keeping their respective orders)

Comment: . . To be more verbose.  A `union` will typically order its results to remove duplicates.  The ordering is then unrelated to the union itself.  A `union all` would, in practice, probably keep the results in order, but ANSI is quite clear that the results are unordered.  You can just put an `order by` after everything -- using a variable in each subquery to identify the group.